# Asus Eee PC keyboard is locked in 10-key mode on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I have an Asus Eee PC (netbook with 8" screen), running Ubuntu 10.04.

The keyboard has gone into some kind of '10-key mode', i.e. typing

- u/U → 4
- i/I → 5
- o/O → 6
- m/M → 0

It happens in all utilites for KDE desktop (word-processor, etc.) and in terminal.

I can't even type in the root password in terminal to try and see what's going on. For example, the password yields `g0ht5d` instead of `gmhtid`.

I'm pretty used to figuring these things out, but, when you can't sign-on as root, how are you going to figure it out?

Comment: Can you connect an external keyboard and try if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have the NUM LOCK on. This is very frustrating setting!

There's going to be a [FUNCTION] key + some other key combo to toggle it on and off.

Comment: [CTRL]+[NUMLOCK] toggles this option. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

On my Asus it was the (FN) + (num lock) keys held down together.